# org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported Exception in spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, postman, restful-authentication

I am developing a spring boot based web application. thyme leaf is the template used. Currently csrf is enabled in my application.
what i did was created a rest controller and sent a post request from postman as well as ajax request to the application. Then i got below exception.

```
org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException:
    Request method 'POST' not supported\r\n\tat
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.handleNoMatch(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:213)\r\n\tat
    org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lookupHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:422)\r\n\tat
    org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:367)\r\n\tat
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:110)\r\n\tat
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:59)\r\n\tat
    org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:395)\r\n\tat
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1234)\r\n\tat
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1016)\r\n\tat
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)\r\n\tat
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)\r\n\tat
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)\r\n\tat
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)\r\n\tat
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)\r\n\tat
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)\r\n\tat
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)\r\n\tat
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\r\n\tat
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:113)\r\n\tat
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:113)\r\n\tat
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:113)\r\n\tat
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)\r\n\tat
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459)\r\n\tat
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384)\r\n\tat
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)\r\n\tat
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequestDispatcher.forward(HeaderWriterFilter.java:172)\r\n\tat
    org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl.handle(AccessDeniedHandlerImpl.java:73)\r\n\tat
    org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:135)\r\n\tat
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\r\n\tat
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)\r\n\tat
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)\r\n\tat
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\r\n\tat
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)\r\n\tat
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\r\n\tat
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)\r\n\tat
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\r\n\tat
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)\r\n\tat
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)\r\n\tat
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)\r\n\tat
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)\r\n\tat
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat
    org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\r\n\tat
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat
    org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\r\n\tat
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\r\n\tat
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)\r\n\tat
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)\r\n\tat
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)\r\n\tat
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)\r\n\tat
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\r\n\tat
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)\r\n\tat
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)\r\n\tat
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)\r\n\tat
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)\r\n\tat
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)\r\n\tat
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589)\r\n\tat
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\r\n\tat
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
```

Below is my security configuration.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
 
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
 
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;
 
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }
 
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
 
        // Setting Service to find User in the database.
        // And Setting PassswordEncoder
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
 
    }
 
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
 
      //  http.csrf().disable();
 
        // The pages does not require login
      //  http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/login", "/logout").permitAll();
 
        // /userInfo page requires login as ROLE_USER or ROLE_ADMIN.
        // If no login, it will redirect to /login page.
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/userInfo").access("hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN')");
 
        // For ADMIN only.
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')");
 
        // When the user has logged in as XX.
        // But access a page that requires role YY,
        // AccessDeniedException will be thrown.
        http.authorizeRequests().and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
 
        // Config for Login Form
        http.authorizeRequests().and().formLogin()//
                // Submit URL of login page.
                .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check") // Submit URL
                .loginPage("/login")//
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/userAccountInfo")//
                .failureUrl("/login?error=true")//
                .usernameParameter("username")//
                .passwordParameter("password")
                // Config for Logout Page
                .and().logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/logoutSuccessful");
 
        // Config Remember Me.
        http.authorizeRequests().and() //
                .rememberMe().tokenRepository(this.persistentTokenRepository()) //
                .tokenValiditySeconds(1 * 24 * 60 * 60); // 24h
 
    }
 
    @Bean
    public PersistentTokenRepository persistentTokenRepository() {
        JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl db = new JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl();
        db.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return db;
    }
 
}
```

Below is the rest controller class.

```
@RestController
public class RestController1 {

     @PostMapping("/person/newperson")
      public void addPerson(@RequestBody Person person) {
       
        System.out.println("Saving person information");
        
      }
}
```

When i disabling the csrf this will work. My question is, Is there any way to work it without disabling csrf? Is it possible sent post request from postman then how?

Comment: are these all classes are part of same package?

Comment: With csrf enabled, did you receive the csrf token from a GET request or response? If yes, did you add the X-CSRF-TOKEN header for the post request in postman?